# Superscript attribute no longer working on iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I have recently noticed that Superscripted text as an NSAttributedString no longer works on iOS 10.3.

Has anyone else noticed this? This code used to work and make my registered symbol superscript:

```
func setSuperScript(forSuperScriptString superScriptString:String, withFont font:String, atSize size:CGFloat){

    if self.text != nil {

        let mutableAttString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:self.text!)

        for (i,c) in self.text!.characters.enumerated() {

            if c == Character(superScriptString) {

                let range = NSRange(location:i,length:1)

                // for each occurence of the character to superscript
                mutableAttString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: font, size: size)!, range: range)
                mutableAttString.addAttribute(kCTSuperscriptAttributeName as String, value:1, range: range)
            }
        }

        self.attributedText = mutableAttString
    }
}
```

This line `mutableAttString.addAttribute(kCTSuperscriptAttributeName as String, value:1, range: range)` works on devices running iOS 10.2 but doesn't on the latest version of iOS.

Comment: What *exactly* is no longer working? Please show some Swift (?) code that worked before and does no longer work.

Comment: https://openradar.appspot.com/31321619 ?

Comment: Not just me then! Thx.

Comment: Could you check by doing a addAttribute with baseline to 0 for the whole attributed string when you create it, then do your for loop and the superscript?

Comment: I have the same problem, and adding a baseline 0 for the entire range seems to fix most problems on iOS 10.3. Not all though, there remain some oddities: some characters are displayed in a "super super script" font: displayed higher and smaller. For example characters 2 and 3 (but not 4, 5, 6 etc) o (which becomes the "degrees" symbol)

Answer (score 0):

I have this code to superscript cents on a currency label and it works very well since iOS 8 to 10.3.1:

```
func formatLabelToCurrency(label: UILabel)-> UILabel {
    var decimalSeparator: String = "."
    let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:20)
    let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:10)
    let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: label.text!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font!])
    attString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:fontSuper!,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:10], range: NSRange(location:(label.text?.index(of: decimalSeparator))!,length:3))
    label.attributedText = attString;
    return label
}
```

Comment: Good fix. I have used this to fix my problem. But, it isn't the answer, and it does seem that this is either a bug in iOS 10.3 or a deprecation.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug in iOS 10.3 when attributes are applied to a string range. It also happens with other attributes.